# Python replace a line only if it meets a condition

Tags: python

I am trying to search through a jsp file, see if it contains a certain tag, and replace an attribute on the same line if the tag exists on the same line.

For example `<c:out var="taskToRedirect" property="dueDate"`

I am trying to see if the line contains `<c:out` and if it does, I need to change the "property" attribute to "value", and only on that line, I don't want to change all of the "property" attributes in the entire file.

Currently what I have is:

```
f = open(filepath)
c = f.read()
for i in c:
    if ("<c:out" in i):
        c=c.replace(i,i.replace("property","value"))
 f.write(c)
 f.close()
```

The code appears to do nothing, and throws no run time errors, c is the string representation of the contents of a file, and i is the current line in the file. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is `c` a list of the lines in the file?

Comment: `c` is the contents of the file. i is an individual line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you write the output.  The file doesn't change unless you write out those changes.  **c** is only your internal copy.

Have you traced whether **c** changes as expected?  Have you tried this with a small file?